# ros run couldn't find executable file after catkin build and source

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run an executable, but I'm getting the following error, I ran

```
catkin build
```

and then

```
source ~/emvs_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

after this running the following command

```
rosrun mapper_emvs run_emvs
```

shows this meassage

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run_emvs below /home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs
```

this is the cmake file:

```
project(mapper_emvs)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo) # Release, RelWithDebInfo
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(HEADERS
  include/mapper_emvs/mapper_emvs.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/data_loading.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/depth_vector.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/trajectory.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/geometry_utils.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/median_filtering.hpp
)

set(SOURCES
  src/mapper_emvs.cpp
  src/data_loading.cpp
  src/median_filtering.cpp
)

option(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH "Use linear spacing in inverse depth (if OFF, will use linear spacing in depth)" ON)
if(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
endif(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)

cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Executables
################################################################################

cs_add_executable(run_emvs src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(run_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME})

################################################################################
cs_install()
cs_export()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358884/ros-run-couldn%27t-find-executable-file-after-catkin-build-and-source/) by [M.Halwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/55796/m.halwani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-08-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-08-07**:
Title seems to be in trouble :O

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-07**:
@M.Halwani: please fix the title.

If you don't, and this is a spam account, I'll remove all the content and block the user account.

**Comment by [M.Halwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/55796/m.halwani/) on 2020-08-07**:
what is the problem with the title ! I'm not a spam account :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-07**:
The title was this, before I changed it: `Public Stack Overflow Tags Users Find a Job Jobs Companies Teams What’s this? Free 30 Day Trial`.

That doesn't seem like a proper title for this forum, and seems like someone trying to use ROS Answers to spam.

**Comment by [M.Halwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/55796/m.halwani/) on 2020-08-07**:
I'm sorry but I didn;t see this title at all in my browser ! I don't know what's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using `catkin_make` instead of `catkin build` solved the issue !

---

Originally posted by [M.Halwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/55796/m.halwani/) with karma: 11 on 2020-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0